# How to find lat and long by splitting shortest path into several distances

Tags: geolocation, coordinates, geospatial, shortest-path, osmnx

Say, I had found a shortest path/route from start_node to end_node, using osmnx shortest path. Here is the sample code:

```
route = nx.shortest_path(g, start_node, end_node, weight='length')
shortest_dist = nx.shortest_path_length(g, start_node, end_node, weight='length')
```

it turns out that the distance is 934 m. And here what it looks in the graph:
[image]

How can I get a lat and long coordinates for every 100 m of my shortest route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the route's geometry and then interpolate points along it: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_geo.interpolate_points

Comment: Thanks Geoff, I have a little bit hesitation. It is said that the param of dist should be in the same unit of geom. And also I have converted my route (shortest path) into LineString geometry. Then, am I right to assume that the unit length of my geom is in WSG84. If so, then how do I fit 100m into the unit length of my geom ?

Comment: If your geometry is unprojected (ie, units of decimal degrees) then you should project it to a meter-based projection to put it in units of meters.